# upload photo with jquery with form input file

Tags: php, jquery, upload

With this code I post form id `fullfsbmut` with click a id `fullforms`, and receive  result of `php` in div id `alerterrorrr`.

I receive all forms, but I can't receive the input file

```
<script>
    $('#fullforms').click(function() {
        $.post('fullstep1.php',$("#fullfsbmut").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#alerterrorrr').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

php file of fullstep1.php

```
<?php session_start(); include_once("dbcon.php");


 ?>
<?php 
function resize_image($file, $directory, $max_width = 200, $max_height = 170) 
{ 
$full_file = $directory.$file;//ãæÞÚ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáßÇãá ãÚ ÇáÇãÊÏÇÏ 
//ãÚÑÝÉ äæÚ ÇáÕæÑÉ Ëã ÇäÔÇÁ ÕæÑÉ Úáì ÎáÝíÊåÇ 
if (eregi("\.png$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$img = imagecreatefrompng($full_file); 
} 

if (eregi("\.(jpg|jpeg)$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($full_file); 
} 

if (eregi("\.gif$", $full_file))
{ 
$img = imagecreatefromgif($full_file); 
} 

if (eregi("\.bmp$", $full_file))
{ 
$img = imagecreatefromwbmp($full_file); 
} 

$FullImage_width = imagesx($img);//ÚÑÖ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÇÕáíÉ 
$FullImage_height = imagesy($img);//ÇÑÊÝÇÚ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÇÕáíÉ 
//ÊÍÏíÏ ÚÑÖ æÇÑÊÝÇÚ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÌÏíÏÉ 
if (isset($max_width) && isset($max_height) && $max_width != 0 && $max_height != 0) 
{ 
$new_width = $max_width; 
$new_height = $max_height; 
} 
elseif (isset($max_width) && $max_width != 0)//ÇÐÇ áã íÍÏÏ ÇáÇÑÊÝÇÚ äÞæã ÈÊÍÏíÏå ÈÇáÊäÇÓÈ ãÚ ÇáÚÑÖ 
{ 
$new_width = $max_width; 
$new_height = ((int)($new_width * $FullImage_height) / $FullImage_width); 
} 
elseif (isset($max_height) && $max_height != 0)//ÇÐÇ áã íÍÏÏ ÇáÚÑÖ äÞæã ÈÊÍÏíå ÈÇáÊäÇÓÈ ãÚ ÇáÇÑÊÝÇÚ 
{ 
$new_height = $max_height; 
$new_width = ((int)($new_height * $FullImage_width) / $FullImage_height); 
} 
else 
{ 
$new_height = $FullImage_height; 
$new_width = $FullImage_width; 
} 

$full_id = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);//ÇäÔÇÁ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÌÏíÏÉ 
imagecopyresampled($full_id, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $FullImage_width, $FullImage_height);//äÓÎ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÞÏíãÉ Úáì ÇáÌÏíÏÉ æÈÇáÇÈÚÇÏ ÇáÌÏíÏÉ 

//ãæÞÚ æÇãÊÏÇÏ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÌÏíÏÉ 
if (eregi("\.(jpg|jpeg)$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$full = imagejpeg($full_id, $full_file, 60); 
} 

if (eregi("\.png$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$full = imagepng($full_id, $full_file); 
} 

if (eregi("\.gif$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$full = imagegif($full_id, $full_file); 
} 

if (eregi("\.bmp$", $full_file)) 
{ 
$full = imagewbmp($full_id, $full_file); 
} 


imagedestroy($full_id);//ÍÐÝ ÇáÕæÑÉ ÇáÞÏíãÉ 
unset($max_width);//ÍÐÝ ÇáãÊÛíÑÇÊ 
unset($max_height); 
} 

//ÇáÇÈÚÇÏ ÍÓÈ ÇáÍÇÌÉ ÊÓÊØíÚ ÊÛííÑ ÈÚÏ æÇÍÏ æÇáÈÚÏ ÇáÇÎÑ íÊÛíÑ ÈÇäÊÙÇã ãÚ ÇáÈÚÏ ÇáãÍÏÏ 
?>


<?php 


function rand_string($num_chars)
{
    $chars = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");
    $string = array_rand($chars, $num_chars);
    foreach($string as $s)
    {
        $ret .= $chars[$s];
    }
    return $ret;
}  


$date = time();
$dat2e = md5(rand_string(8));?>
<?
if (isset($_COOKIE['id'])){
$title=$_POST['title'];
$photo=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$contery=$_POST['contery'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$showmobile=$_POST['showmobile'];

if(!$title){die('عنوان الاعلان غير مكتمل');}
if($_FILES['photo']['name']){die('برجاء اختيار صورة للاعلان');}
if(!$message){die('وصف الاعلان غير مكتمل');}
if(!$price){die('برجاء وضع السعر المحدد لاعلانك بالجنية المصري');}
if(!$contery){die('اختر الدولة');}
if(!$mobile){die('ملحوظة لم تضع رقم موبيلك سوف تفقد التواصل بالاعلان'.'<br/>');}
if(!$showmobile){echo'سوف لن يتم اظهار رقمك داخل هذة الاعلان';}

?><br/><a style="
width: 100%;
position: relative;

color: green;">جاري اضافة اعلانك خلال 5 ثواني</a>
<?


$message= strip_tags($message, '<br>');
$ddir='textads/'.date("Ymd").'/'. md5(time() + mt_rand()) . '.txt';
file_put_contents('./'.$ddir, $message);
$ssssdfgsadfgdfs=strlen($message); 
if($ssssdfgsadfgdfs>'10000'){ 
unlink('../'.$ddir);
die('وصف الموضوع يحتوي علي اكتر من 10 الاف حرف');
}

$newphotopath = $date.$dat2e.$_FILES["photo"]["name"] ;
    $uploadDir = './photos/'.date("Ymd").'/';
    $nomFichier = $_FILES["photo"]["name"] ;
    $nomTemporaire = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"] ;
    $uploadOk = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDir.$newphotopath);
    resize_image($newphotopath,$uploadDir,  280, 218); 

$urlofimg='/photos/'.date("Ymd").'/'.$date.$dat2e.$_FILES["photo"]["name"];

$iiiiid=$_COOKIE['id'];
$DB = new DB;       
$SQL_Insert_tripdata ="INSERT INTO ads(userid,title,photo,message,price,contery,mobile,showmobile)  VALUES
('$iiiiid','$title','$urlofimg','$ddir','$price','$contery','$mobile','$showmobile') ";
$result = $DB->query($SQL_Insert_tripdata);
$used_id =  mysql_insert_id();


}
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=add2-2.php?id=<? echo $used_id; ?>">
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't receive the input file ? You want to display an uploaded image the same way as you display the submitted text fields value ? Is that it ?

Comment: i update with php file to see what i mean